# Spring Security OAuth2 /oauth/token endpoint after Basic auth success then no access token

Tags: spring, oauth, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I am adding spring security oauth2 to my spring boot application.  I have followed a few of the examples on the web and in github from the spring team (had to make some mods for my use case), but I am still not able to return an oauth2 access token from the /oauth/token endpoint.  I have been working on this for several days and started off trying to do it in JavaConfig, but then switched to xml config and was able to make some progress.  I should note the only config I am doing in xml is the security config and related security beans, all other config is done via JavaConfig.

I am able to successfully authenticate my user (using username & password) using Basic auth, but when it comes to the next step to generate and return the bearer token, this is not happening.  Note, I am using a database for storing my user credentials and to store my access tokens (once they get created).

I am making a POST request using grant_type=password with a client id and client secret.

I am under the impression spring oauth2 would handle creating the access token for me and returning it, but maybe this isn't correct or my xml config maybe wrong? Many thanks for any assistance!

Here is my security config xml below:

```
<http pattern="/oauth/token" 
    create-session="stateless"        
    authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" method="GET" access="ROLE_DENY" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" method="PUT" access="ROLE_DENY" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" method="DELETE" access="ROLE_DENY" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" />
    <anonymous enabled="false" />
    <http-basic entry-point-ref="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint" />
    <!-- include this only if you need to authenticate clients via request 
        parameters>
    <custom-filter ref="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter"
        after="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" /-->
    <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
</http>

<http pattern="/**" create-session="never" 
    entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint" 
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <!-- authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager"
    access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"-->
    <anonymous enabled="false" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" />
    <custom-filter ref="resourceServerFilter" before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" />
    <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
</http>

<bean id="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <!-- property name="realmName" value="f2rRealm" /-->
</bean>

<bean id="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <property name="realmName" value="f2r/client" />
    <property name="typeName" value="Basic" />
</bean>

<bean id="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter">
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
</bean>

<bean id="oauthAccessDeniedHandler"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler" />

<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" >
    <!-- authentication-provider user-service-ref="clientDetailsUserService"  /-->
    <authentication-provider ref="authenticationProvider" />
</authentication-manager>

<bean id="clientDetails" class="com.f2r.security.oauth2.F2RJdbcClientDetailsService" >
    <constructor-arg ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="clientId" value="f2r" />
    <property name="clientSecret" value="f2rsecret" />
    <property name="passwordEncoder" ref="passwordEncoder" />
</bean>

<!-- bean id="clientDetailsService"
    class="com.f2r.security.oauth2.F2RJdbcClientDetailsService">
    <constructor-arg ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="clientDetails" ref="clientDetails" />
    <property name="passwordEncoder" ref="passwordEncoder" />
</bean-->

<bean id="clientDetailsUserService"
    class="com.f2r.security.oauth2.F2RClientDetailsUserDetailsService">
    <constructor-arg ref="clientDetails" />
    <property name="passwordEncoder" ref="passwordEncoder" />
</bean>    


<authentication-manager id="userAuthenticationManager"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <!-- authentication-provider ref="customUserAuthenticationProvider" /-->
    <authentication-provider ref="authenticationProvider" />
</authentication-manager>

<!-- bean id="customUserAuthenticationProvider" class="com.f2r.security.F2RAuthenticationProvider">
    <property name="userDetailsService" ref="userDetailsService" />
</bean-->

<bean id="authenticationProvider" class="com.f2r.security.F2RAuthenticationProvider">
    <!-- property name="userDetailsService" ref="userDetailsService" /-->
    <property name="userDetailsService" ref="clientDetailsUserService" />
</bean>

<bean id="userDetailsService" class="com.f2r.security.F2RUserDetailsService" />

<bean id="userApprovalHandler" 
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.approval.TokenStoreUserApprovalHandler">
    <property name="tokenStore" ref="tokenStore" />
    <property name="clientDetailsService" ref="clientDetails" /> 
    <property name="requestFactory" ref="requestFactory" />  
</bean>

<bean id="requestFactory"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.request.DefaultOAuth2RequestFactory">
    <constructor-arg ref="clientDetails" />
</bean>

<oauth:authorization-server
    client-details-service-ref="clientDetails" 
    token-services-ref="tokenServices" 
    token-endpoint-url="/oauth/token" 
    authorization-endpoint-url="/oauth/authorize" >
    <oauth:implicit />
    <oauth:refresh-token />
    <oauth:client-credentials />
    <!-- oauth:password authentication-manager-ref="userAuthenticationManager" /-->
    <oauth:password />
</oauth:authorization-server>

<oauth:resource-server id="resourceServerFilter"
    token-services-ref="tokenServices" />

<bean id="tokenStore"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.JdbcTokenStore" >
    <constructor-arg ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>

<bean id="tokenServices"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices">
    <property name="tokenStore" ref="tokenStore" />
    <property name="supportRefreshToken" value="true" />
    <property name="clientDetailsService" ref="clientDetails" />
</bean>     

<mvc:annotation-driven />

<mvc:default-servlet-handler />

<sec:global-method-security
    pre-post-annotations="enabled" proxy-target-class="true">
    <!--you could also wire in the expression handler up at the layer of the 
        http filters. See https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SEC-1452 -->
    <sec:expression-handler ref="oauthExpressionHandler" />
</sec:global-method-security>

<oauth:expression-handler id="oauthExpressionHandler" />

<oauth:web-expression-handler id="oauthWebExpressionHandler" />
```

Comment: Update: I don't believe the request is ever getting to the dispatcher servlet or the controller, I think the request goes through one security filter chain is authenticated via Basic, has a valid and authenticated Authentication object, but then seems to hit another filter chain and the Auth object is remove, and this new filter chain is looking for a Bearer token and never finds one.  So I am thinking this is related to multiple security filter chains being applied.  But I don't know why the second chain is called or why the Authentication object is cleared out after initially being a success

Comment: I think the problem may be with the pattern "/**" on the http section after the http section for /oauth/token.  Changing that to /* might solve the issue.

Comment: did that solve the issue for you?