# remove OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter from/oauth/token filter chain

Tags: spring, oauth, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I am trying to implement OAuth2 into my Spring Boot app.  When making a call to `/oauth/token` using a password grant, I am able to authenticate using Basic auth with a username/password against a database.  The authentication object is loaded into the security context and the filter continues.  However I noticed that further down the line the `OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter` is called and cleans out the security context b/c no OAuth bearer token is found.  This ultimately results in an authentication failure at the `TokenEndpoint.postAccessToken` method (e.g. `/oauth/token`).

Is it expected that the `OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter` would be called during a `/oauth/token` call?  If not, any ideas why? If it is expected what is the best fix/work around for this issue, to set stateless on the `OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter` to false?  Not sure if that is a good idea or not...

Some relevant info, I am using xml config for my spring security settings and JavaConfig for the rest. The grant type is password on the `/oauth/token` call.

Any help is greatly appreciated.  Below are some log messages for context on what I am seeing.

```
09/30/15 22:42:50.899 [http-nio-9931-exec-8] DEBUG o.s.s.o.p.c.ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter - Authentication success. Updating SecurityContextHolder to contain: org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.OAuth2Authentication@9d98054f: Principal: testUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_USER
09/30/15 22:42:50.899 [http-nio-9931-exec-8] DEBUG o.s.s.o.p.a.BearerTokenExtractor - Token not found in headers. Trying request parameters.
09/30/15 22:42:50.899 [http-nio-9931-exec-8] DEBUG o.s.s.o.p.a.BearerTokenExtractor - Token not found in request parameters.  Not an OAuth2 request.
09/30/15 22:42:50.899 [http-nio-9931-exec-8] DEBUG o.s.s.o.p.a.OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter - Clearing security context.
09/30/15 22:42:50.900 [http-nio-9931-exec-8] DEBUG o.s.s.o.p.a.OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter - No token in request, will continue chain.
09/30/15 22:42:50.900 [http-nio-9931-exec-8] DEBUG o.s.s.o.p.a.BearerTokenExtractor - Token not found in headers. Trying request parameters.
09/30/15 22:42:50.900 [http-nio-9931-exec-8] DEBUG o.s.s.o.p.a.BearerTokenExtractor - Token not found in request parameters.  Not an OAuth2 request.
09/30/15 22:42:50.900 [http-nio-9931-exec-8] DEBUG o.s.s.o.p.a.OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter - No token in request, will continue chain.
09/30/15 22:42:50.934 [http-nio-9931-exec-8] DEBUG o.s.s.o.p.e.FrameworkEndpointHandlerMapping - Looking up handler method for path /oauth/token
09/30/15 22:42:50.937 [http-nio-9931-exec-8] DEBUG o.s.s.o.p.e.FrameworkEndpointHandlerMapping - Returning handler method [public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<org.springframework.security.oauth2.common.OAuth2AccessToken> org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint.TokenEndpoint.postAccessToken(java.security.Principal,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>) throws org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException]
09/30/15 22:42:50.958 [http-nio-9931-exec-8] INFO  o.s.s.o.p.endpoint.TokenEndpoint - Handling error: InsufficientAuthenticationException, There is no client authentication. Try adding an appropriate authentication filter.
09/30/15 22:42:51.070 [http-nio-9931-exec-8] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter - Chain processed normally
09/30/15 22:42:51.070 [http-nio-9931-exec-8] DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

Comment: Have you made any progress on this?  We have exactly the same problem. If you have found a solution, could you post it?

Comment: @bischoje I got so frustrated with this I ended up bailing on OAuth2 and went with basic auth.  But then I hit a similar problem with my Basic auth security config as well.  And what my problem was, is in my security config xml, in the http section following a http section where security="none", the following http section had a pattern of "/**" which is the universal matching pattern.  Once I changed that to "/*" in my config xml it worked perfectly.  I haven't had a chance to go back and try it in my OAuth2 config yet.  Let me know if it works.

Comment: @bischoje here is a similar question I opened that shows my security xml config for OAuth2, thought it might be helpful to see my bad xml and combine with my previous comment for a possible fix.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32838172/spring-security-oauth2-oauth-token-endpoint-after-basic-auth-success-then-no-ac